# Canvas Layout is not working properly

Tags: android, canvas, surfaceview, ondraw

I have created a map by drawing rectangles on a canvas by using OnDraw method.This worked perfectly on Samsung s2 but when i installed it in s3 the canvas seems too small.. What should i do?

I have used Surface views to draw the rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

The Galaxy S2 is hdpi and the S3 is xhdpi, so that's probably why the rectangles are appearing a bit smaller. I would suggest overriding on onMeasure and then set your rectangles height and width based on the current height and width of your canvas.

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
int parentViewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
int parentViewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
// ... take into account the parent's size as needed ...
super.onMeasure(
    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(newWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), 
    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(newHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
```

}

EDIT: Just realized you said you used SurfaceView to draw your rectangles and not View. In your onDraw, just get the current height and width of the canvas and draw your rectangles based on those dimensions rather than hardcoding fixed dimensions for your rectangles. Hope this helps

Comment: i have already implemented a separate database with the rectangle coordinates coz i am doing a shortest path analysis. so i cant change the rectangle coordinates for any reason.
I have web services where i retrieve rectangle coordinates. it worked perfectly on S2.. but not in S3 :( and i got no idea how to fix it!